# How can I have a state notifier provider that's instanciated when the app is started?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have a Flutter app that contains multiple riverpod state notifier providers. Some of them need to be called before the app is launched, how can i achieve this?

If there's a simpler way to do this I will gladly accept suggestions.

Comment: You can do it inside `HomeWidget` is there any FutureProvider? `stateProvider` can be added easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call it when you register your `StateNotifier`. For example:

```dart
final gpsHandlerProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<GpsHandlerNotifier, bool>((ref) {
  return GpsHandlerNotifier()..checkGps();
});
```

Thanks to `cascade notation` in Dart.